# Use JSON in kubectl run env

Tags: kubernetes

What's the right way to escape the env in this command?

```
kubectl run latency-check \
  --env="POST='{""foo"": ""bar"", ""baz"": ""qux""}'" \
  -i --rm --restart=Never --image devth/alpine-bench:0.1 -- -n30 \
  http://google.com/
```

This currently errors with `error: invalid env:  baz: qux}'`.

A simpler form of JSON in the `env` works:

```
kubectl run latency-check \
  --env="POST='{""foo"": ""bar""}'" \
  -i --rm --restart=Never --image devth/alpine-bench:0.1 -- -n30 \
  http://google.com/
```

So it seems I need to escape commas in the env?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/18997